# Does the php mail() function work in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, email

This relates to another question I posted here but it's a 
different matter so I hope people don't think I'm double posting.

I have an email form in Wordpress like this.

html

```
    <form action="" id="contactForm">
        <input type="text" id="contactName" placeholder="Name:">
        <input type="text" id="contactEmail" placeholder="Email:">
        <select id="form-subject">
          <option>Subject</option>
          <option>Accounts</option>
          <option>Bookkeeping</option>
          <option>Start Up</option>
          <option>CIS Returns</option>
          <option>Payroll</option>
          <option>Self Assessment</option>
          <option>Tax Returns</option>
          <option>VAT Returns</option>
                        <option>Other</option>
        </select>  
        <textarea id="contactMessage" rows="8" cols="40" placeholder="Message:"></textarea>
                    <p id="submit">Submit</p>
                    <div id="status">
          <p></p>
        </div>
    </form>
```

jquery

```
    $j('#submit').click(function(){     
        //
        var nameVal = $j('#contactForm #contactName').val();
        var emailVal = $j('#contactForm #contactEmail').val();
        var messageVal = $j('#contactForm #contactMessage').val();

        //
        $j.post('wp-content/code/contactEngine.php', { theName:nameVal, theEmail:emailVal, theMessage:messageVal }, function(data){
            $j("#status p").html(data);
            $j("#status p").show().fadeOut(3500);
            if(data.indexOf('Thank You')==0) {document.forms[0].reset();}
        });
    })
```

php

```
    <?php

      $errors = array();
      $required_fields = array('theName','theEmail','theMessage');
      foreach($required_fields as $fieldname){
         if(!isset($_POST[$fieldname]) || empty($_POST[$fieldname])){
            $errors[] = $fieldname;
         }
      }
      if(empty($errors)){
         $name_field = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['theName']));
         $name = explode(' ', $name_field);
         $firstname = ucfirst($name[0]);
         $email_field = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['theEmail']));
         $message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['theMessage']));
         //
         $to = "info@ttmt.org.uk";
         $subject = "Email from Website";
         $body = "From: $name_field\n E-Mail: $email_field\n Message:\n $message";
         //
         mail($to, $subject, $body);

             //wp_mail($to, $subject, $body);   

         echo "Thank You $firstname";
      }else{
         echo "Please complete all fields.";
      }

    ?>
```

The php is in a folder in the wp-content folder so it's easy for the jquery to access it.

```
$j.post('wp-content/code/contactEngine.php', { theName:nameVal, theEmail:emailVal, theMessage:messageVal }, function(data){
```

The variables reach the php and echo back a reply if the form is complete or not.

The actual email isn't sent - Does the php mail() function work in Worpdress.

I tried the wp_mail() function but this stops the script completely and I don't get the echo.

I know there are email plugins like Contact Form 7 but I don't think they will work with this site.

It's a single page site with a Custom Post Type, I'm not calling any content, which I think I ned to do with Contact Form 7.

Answer (score 1):

The PHP mail function is absolutely independent from Wordpress. It's a built in PHP function, and in theory should work across all platforms.

The only thing that comes to my mind is a problem with your server configuration. Maybe your hsoting blocks the mail function, or it's not set up properly.

See if this example works in a stand-alone file (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php):

```
<?php
    $to      = 'nobody@example.com';
    $subject = 'the subject';
    $message = 'hello';
    $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks ZorleQ. I'm actually working locally in MAMP. This same script works in MAMP when it's outside Wordpress.

Comment: Does that mean it fails locally (in MAMP) when integrated with WordPress, or does it means it fails on a hosted site when integrated with WordPress? There are two variables here; make sure you've separated their influences.

Comment: It fails locally (in MAMP) with Wordpress. I haven't tried it hosted yet.

Comment: If your script works outside wordpress but fails from within, then WP must be changing some configuration. Try setting your `sendmail_from` and `mail.log` using `ini_set()` just before you execute the mail function. See http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php  and http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php for details.

Comment: ZorleQ, I can't see how to use sendmail_from and mail.log. sendmail_from, it's from Wordpress? If I try to use mail.log() the mail is red and crashes the script.

Comment: It really doesn't matter if it's Wordpress or Joomla or yur own script, it's still PHP.
In your script, just before the mail function put `ini_set('mail.log', '/var/log/pap_mail_log.log');` (of course, change the path to a real path).

Comment: On a completely different topic, have you got an actual SMTP server running on your machine? You can't send mail without an SMTP server. Also, make sure you have specified a valid SMTP server and port in your PHP ini file using `SMTP = server.com` and `smtp_port = 25` (change as appropriate). Youc an use it to specify external servers if you don't have one running on your machine - like google or your ISP.

Comment: I have moved the Wordpress to a live site and it all works, so the problem is Wordpress in MAMP. So how do I get it working in MAMP. SMTP server running - how would i know? Would I need a SMTP server for this email script to work in MAMP when it's not in Wordpress. This code in MAMP WITHOUT Wordpress works. This code in MAMP WITH Wordpress doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to solve a similar problem. Things that might get it to work might include:

1. Follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19484309/sending-emails-in-wordpress) example (or similar) to structure your code - don't know if it has any real effect.
2. Experiment with providing headers, including the form from this example:

   `$headers = array('From: From someone <some@one.com>'. "\r\n",'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');`
3. Do not allow empty variables enter the message, subject or headers - initialize them with an empty string or similar -> `$myvar='';`
4. If your subject contains multibyte characters or similar, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447560/php-mail-encodes-subject-line).

Comment: And also - I solved it. It works using either mail() or wp_mail(). wp_mail() seems to need the array-style header.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not including the wordpress files (wp-load.php and etc.) it's a "normal" PHP, having nothing in common with others wordpress files, **besides it's location**, so the problem should be some config in the .htaccess files or other directory config I guess. Are you using a virtual host just for WP or something like that?