# Arabic Issue with PHPMailer

Tags: php, encoding, phpmailer

I am using PHPMailer and trying to send email with the Arabic text, It's sending the Empty Subject , I can see in my Inbox "(no subject)"

I am using following :

HTML code

```
<form action="mail.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="subject" />
<input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

PHP Code (mail.php)

```
$subject = $_POST["subject"];
    $mailer = new PHPMailer();
            $mailer->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
            $mailer->IsSMTP();
            $mailer->SMTPDebug = 1;
            $mailer->SMTPAuth = true;



            // Prepare Message  
            $mailer->Subject = ($subject);
            $emails = 0;
```

Help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Is that your full code?

Comment: Actually! subject is coming from $_POST so, I think you should understand the code

Comment: What is your $_POST set as, in both the form and process? To add, I usually am better at helping when I have full code, but that's just me ;-)

Comment: just edited code.. now you should understand :)

Comment: Have you tried `$mailer->Subject = "$subject";` ?

Comment: Any luck on my above said comment/suggestion?

Comment: I am Sorry Fred , Same issue, it's working fine for the Message Body, but not for subject. It seems PHPMailer Issue...

Comment: Hm... that's a shame. I'll see what else I can find out for you.

Comment: Ok, I can't find anything yet however and I have been criticized about this in the past, the infamous `BOM` (byte order mark), are you aware of the term?

Comment: To add to my above recent comment: UTF-8 encoding can be saved either `with` or `without` the `BOM` which at many times, can cause problems for many and in so many ways, so it can't be left out of the equation.

Comment: New findings: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/447560/php-mail-encodes-subject-line and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334935/how-do-i-send-emails-with-arabic-content-via-phps-mail-function and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389676/php-email-header-subject-encoding-problem

Answer (score 12):

just add

```
$mailer->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
```

and its works

Comment: This is actually a valid answer, or at least it fixed the problem I faced (which is the same as the author of the question)

Answer (score 5):

use this. its worked for me.

```
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';       
    $mail->IsSMTP();                                   // send via SMTP
    $mail->Encoding     = "base64";
    $mail->Host     = ........

    ...

    $mail->Subject  =  '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=';
```

if you have `htmlentities ($subject)` change it to `htmlspecialchars ($subject)` htmlenitities breaks encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following steps to address the problem correctly.

1. Make sure the page that's posting the subject is a UTF-8 encoded page.

   1a. If the source isn't UTF-8, then

   ```
   iconv("SOURCE_ENCODING","UTF-8",$subject);
   ```
2. Var Dump the subject before sending the mail.
3. Try to add a hard-coded subject in Arabic, e.g.:

   ```
   $subject= "تجربة عنوان للرسالة";
   ```

Comment: Thanks, I tried all even hard coded... actually it seems error of PHPMailer, I tested it's printing Arabic on Page very good, but not in email :(

Answer (score 1):

```
$subject = $_POST["subject"];
$subject = "=?UTF-8?B?" . base64_encode($subject) . "?=";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the old way:

```
$to      = 'any@mail.com';
$subject = 'Hi!';
$message = 'Whats up?';
$headers = 'From: mail@of.you.com' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: noreply@blabla.com' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion()."\r\n";                         
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
//if you send an html page:
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
ALTER DATABASE databasename CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
ALTER TABLE tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

and add
$mailer->CharSet = 'UTF-8';